# How to prove theorems about recursive functions of ListMap in coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to learn to use the `ListMap` module in Coq. I'm really not sure about proving properties about the keys or values in a `ListMap`, when the `ListMap` is created by a recursive function. I feel like I do not know what tactics to use.

```
(* Me proving statements about maps to understand how to use maps in Coq *)

Require Import FunInd.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.


Require Import
  Coq.FSets.FMapList
  Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.

Module Import MNat := FMapList.Make(Nat_as_OT).
Require Import
        Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.

Definition NatToNat := MNat.t nat.
Definition NatToNatEmpty : NatToNat := MNat.empty nat.

(* We wish to show that map will have only positive values *)
Function insertNats (n: nat)  (mm: NatToNat)  {struct n}: NatToNat :=
  match n with
  | O => mm
  | S (next) => insertNats  next (MNat.add n n mm)
  end.


Definition keys (mm: NatToNat) : list nat :=
  List.map  fst (elements mm).

(* vvvvv How do I prove this? Intuitively it is true *)
Example keys_nonnegative: forall (n: nat),
    forall (k: nat),
      List.In k (keys (insertNats n NatToNatEmpty)) -> k >= 0.
Proof.
  intros n k in_proof.
  induction n.
  simpl in in_proof. tauto.
  (* ??? NOW WHAT *)
Admitted.
```

Informally, the argument I would use for the below program is that because `n >= 0` because it is a `nat`, the keys inserted into the map by `idMapsGo` will also always be non-negative.

I need to induct on `n` for `keys_nonnegative`. On the `nth` step, we add a key `n`, which will be non-negative (due to being a `nat`). The base case is trivial.

However, I am unable to convert this intuition into a Coq proof :)

Comment: Since 'k' is a 'nat' then it is non-negative. Why do you need to look at the contents of the map in this case? Your lemma is trivially proved using "intros. auto with *." as the body of the proof (no induction needed).

Comment: Indeed it is. But that is not the point: The actual example is more complex - I chose to create this artificial example. If it helps, consider it to be Z, not nat.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at [`elements_in_iff`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html#WFacts_fun.elements_in_iff) and [`elements_mapsto_iff`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html#WFacts_fun.elements_mapsto_iff) from [Coq.FSets.FMapFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html).

**Useful properties on keys:**

Here are two useful properties on your definition of keys that might help you simplify your proofs. The code is taken from my own project [Aniceto](https://gitlab.com/cogumbreiro/aniceto-coq/blob/master/src/Map.v#L665) that includes helper properties on maps.

```
  Definition keys {elt:Type} (m:t elt) : list key :=  fst (split (elements m)).

Fixpoint split_alt {A:Type} {B:Type} (l:list (A*B) %type) : (list A * list B) % type:=
  match l with
    | nil => (nil, nil)
    | (x, y) :: l => (x :: (fst (split_alt l)), y :: (snd (split_alt l)))
  end.

Lemma split_alt_spec:
  forall {A:Type} {B:Type} (l:list (A*B) %type),
  split l = split_alt l.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l.
  - auto.
  - simpl. intuition.
    rewrite IHl.
    remember (split_alt l) as l'.
    destruct l' as (lhs, rhs).
    auto.
Qed.

Lemma in_fst_split:
  forall {A:Type} {B:Type} (l:list (A*B)%type) (lhs:A),
  List.In lhs (fst (split l)) ->
  exists rhs, List.In (lhs, rhs) l.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l.
  { inversion H. (* absurd *) }
  destruct a.
  rewrite split_alt_spec in H.
  simpl in H.
  destruct H.
  + subst.
    eauto using in_eq.
  + rewrite <- split_alt_spec in H.
    apply IHl in H; clear IHl.
    destruct H as (r, Hin).
    eauto using in_cons.
Qed.

  Lemma in_elements_to_in:
    forall {elt:Type} k e (m: t elt),
    List.In (k, e) (elements m) ->
    In k m.
  Proof.
    intros.
    rewrite elements_in_iff.
    exists e.
    apply InA_altdef.
    apply Exists_exists.
    exists (k,e).
    intuition.
    unfold eq_key_elt.
    intuition.
  Qed.

  Lemma keys_spec_1:
    forall {elt:Type} (m:t elt) (k:key),
    List.In k (keys m) -> In k m.
  Proof.
    intros.
    unfold keys in *.
    apply in_fst_split in H.
    destruct H as (e, H).
    apply in_elements_to_in with (e0:=e).
    assumption.
  Qed.

  Lemma keys_spec_2:
    forall {elt:Type} (m:t elt) (k:key),
    In k m ->
    exists k', E.eq k k' /\ List.In k' (keys m).
  Proof.
    intros.
    unfold keys in *.
    destruct H as (e, H).
    apply maps_to_impl_in_elements in H.
    destruct H as (k', (Heq, Hin)).
    apply in_split_l in Hin.
    exists k'.
    intuition.
  Qed.
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I shall check your proof and understand how it works, this is much appreciated :)

Comment: Hm, I am unable to find `in_fst_split` at `apply List.in_fst_split in H`.

Comment: I've added lemma `in_fst_split`. The full source is available here: https://gitlab.com/cogumbreiro/aniceto-coq/blob/master/src/List.v under a public domain license.